# VIA VT6421A RAID controller on MSI KT4V motherboard not bootable

Tags: windows-xp, boot, installation, raid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Booting From VIA VT6421A Based PCI SATA Card](https://superuser.com/questions/17422/booting-from-via-vt6421a-based-pci-sata-card)

I'd like to upgrade my old PC.

**My setup:**

- Motherboard: MSI KT4V (only supports IDE HDDs, no SATA)
- I installed a VIA VT6421A SATA RAID controller + attached a SATA HDD to it.
- I'd like to install Windows XP Professional on that HDD.

**The problem:**

My BIOS doesn't see the HDD at all — I already did a BIOS update but it didn't help. Under boot settings, I can only choose from the IDE HDDs but no SCSI or SATA. When switching on the PC, I can't see anything from the controller's BIOS at all.

When running my "old" XP from the IDE HDD, XP detects the RAID controller and it would probably work using it if I installed the drivers. So the controller is working fine.

**What I've tried so far:**

Run XP setup, choose the SATA drivers — it works, the setup detects the HD and starts
installing files to it. But after the first reboot, setup starts from the beginning again,
as it's not detecting any HDD.

Any idea how to get it working? I'm afraid that it won't work at all, as the motherboard can't see the SATA controller/HDD.

Answer (score 1):

The motherboard BIOS will not detect the external card - it knows nothing about them.  The RAID card has its own BIOS, I'm assuming with the card installed you see a new screen where it shows SATA drives connected.  That's the card's BIOS.

You'll need to set the motherboard's BIOS to boot from SCSI.  Yes your drives aren't SCSI, that setting is really a short cut to boot from external card.  SCSI cards contain their own BIOS and handling booting themselves, just like your SATA card.

Comment: yes that's what i thought - the problem is: my board's bios doesn't have any setting for booting from scsi :(
already did a bios firmware update, didnt help, so i guess i'm lost here.